# Batch equivalent of "source" on Windows: how to run a Python script from a virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, scripting, batch-file, virtualenv

I've done a fair bit of bash scripting, but very little batch scripting on Windows. I'm trying to activate a Python virtualenv, run a Python script, then deactivate the virtualenv when the script exits.

I've got a folder called `env`, which is my virtualenv, and a folder called work, which contains my scripts.

This is what I've got so far:

```
%~dp0env\Scripts\activate.bat
python %~dp0work\script.py
deactivate
```

However, when I run the script, it activates the virtualenv then stops. It does not get to the second line and run the Python script. Is there a way to "source" the activate script folder, so that the rest of the batch script can be run as if I'd called `activate.bat` from the command line?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'd say you just need to prepend 'call' to your activate.bat invocation, to ensure that the current batch file is resumed after activate is executed:

```
call %~dp0env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Consider doing the same for `deactivate.bat`. Furthermore, if you want to ensure that the current cmd.exe environment is not polluted by a call to your batch file, consider wrapping your commands in a `setlocal`/`endlocal` command pair.

Comment: I'll try this out, but this seems like exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicola If batch1.bat contains `batch2.bat` and `echo 1`, and batch2.bat contains `echo 2`, and I run batch1.bat, I see a new shell open, then `2`, then `1`, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: From the "Call" command documentation: "Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program." (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732835%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @Nicola _Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program._ That's not what you want here, right? :)

Comment: It's exactly what we want. The docs aren't very clear, they should say *terminating* rather than *stopping*. What they mean isn't some sort of parallel execution; rather, if you don't use the `call` command the execution of the calling batch is replaced with the execution of the called one, i.e. subsequent instructions in the calling batch are discarded. With the `call` command execution of the calling batch resumes after the called one terminates.

Comment: @jmite if this did solve your problem, it's nice to 'accept' it :)

Answer (score 6):

I made a .lnk file that points to `cmd /k "path/to the/script/activate.bat"`, and it works.

[CMD parameters & options](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you just want to perform the same commands in Windows as if expected in Linux Bash/shell. When I want to start a virtualenv I am actually in its top directory, and the Linux command would be "source bin/activate".

It is no problem to simulate this behaviour on Windows. Me personally, I've put a batch file named `activate.bat` somewhere on the PATH environment variable like this:

```
:: activate.bat
@echo off
REM source bin/activate
if "%1" == "bin/activate" (
    if not EXIST "%CD%\Scripts\activate.bat" goto notfound
    set WRAPEX=Scripts\activate.bat
) ELSE (
       set WRAPEX=%*
)
call %WRAPEX%
goto :eof

:notfound
echo Cannot find the activate script -- aborting.
goto :eof
```