# How to activate conda environment in jenkins build

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, environment, conda

I need to run jenkins build using a specific conda environment on our jenkins server (running on Windows). I thought it would be as easy as running:

```
activate myenv
python test_env.py
```

but this seems to cause the build to exit instead, before the script even starts. Here is the jenkins console log:

```
activate myenv
Activating environment "myenv"...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If I remove the activate line, the python script executes fine.

FYI, the script I am running:

```
import os

f = open('env.txt','w')

for k, v in os.environ.iteritems():
    print k, v
    f.write('%s\t%s\n' % (k,v))
f.close()
```

Does anybody know what is going on? Should I directly call the relevant python executable instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `call activate myenv` to prevent activate from ending the current shell when it is finished. See https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true.

Comment: This worked, although even though it is now in the conda environment, it can't find python.  It seems like the CMD that jenkins doesn't care about which conda environment is active.

Answer (score 4):

Bradley led me in the right direction and I found the solution...

I needed a windows equivalent for the Unix "source", and "call" does the job, as detailed in this other answer.

[batch equivalent of "source" on windows: how to run a python script from a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781799/batch-equivalent-of-source-on-windows-how-to-run-a-python-script-from-a-virtu)

I hope someone will find this helpful in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I think the activate script on Windows starts a new subshell which means the current shell exists immediately.  Can you try manually setting the ENV variables like PATH and such instead of using activate?

Comment: Hi Bradley, Yes I though about doing this, basically prepending the myenv/bin and myenv/Scripts folders to PATH. I asked the question because I don't know what else "activate" does... will this be enough?