# aws-lambda - python tutorial refers to 'virtualenv' and 'source'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to follow the aws-lambda tutorial at

[Sample Amazon S3 Function Code - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python)

It contains lines:

```
...
    1 Create a virtual environment.
    $ virtualenv ~/shrink_venv
    $ source ~/shrink_venv/bin/activate

2 Install libraries in the virtual environment
    $ pip install Pillow
    $ pip install boto3

3 Add the contents of lib and lib64 site-packages to your .zip file.
    $ cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    $ zip -r ~/CreateThumbnail.zip .
    ...
```

These all appear to be done on the command line. How does one get these utilities and find the documentation for them?

I am on Windows 10 running on the command line with Anaconda.

I've also looked in cygwin.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+s3+virtualenv - leads to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-virtualenv.html : "To install the AWS CLI in a virtual environment .. *Install virtualenv using pip* .. Create a virtual environment (using virtualenv) and name it. .."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran these commands in Windows 10 create a virtual environment with python 3

```
pip3 install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv path\to\location\virtualenv-name
cd path\to\location\virtualenv-name
.\Scripts\activate
```

`pip3 install virtualenv` #Install virtualenv module for python3

`python -m virtualenv path\to\location\virtualenv-name` #Creates the virtual environment in the given path. For example E:\test\testing, E:\test is the path and testing is the virtual environment name,

Check this question for the command line equivalent of source command - [Batch equivalent of "source" on Windows: how to run a Python script from a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781799/batch-equivalent-of-source-on-windows-how-to-run-a-python-script-from-a-virtu)